# ArcGIS Javascript API - Dynamic label placement in feature layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, javascript, feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is it possible to use dynamic label placement with a feature layer in the javascript API v3.21 ? For instance, if two point features are superposed, I would like to display their labels at different placement.

The [LabelClass](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/labelclass-amd.html) documentation does not specify this possibility. Is there any solution to achieve this?

Otherwise, is it possible to set a priority to features for labeling. In case two points features are superposed, is it possible to define which feature's label will be displayer on the map?